# keep the menu closed after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Hello i have a menu when it's open it have a class: `left_right_section` and when its closed it have two classes: `left_right_section` and `leftpanel_collapse`. I need that when the user close the menu and refresh the page or go to another page in the app  the menu should still closed, and if it's open it should still opened so i check the local storage if the menu is closed or not but my code is not working:

```
if (document.querySelector('.leftpanel_collapse') !== null) { 
  localStorage.ClassName = 'leftpanel_collapse';
}
   
function SetClass() {
  // before assigning class check local storage if it has any value
  $('.left_right_section').addClass(localStorage.ClassName);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  SetClass();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use functions `getItem()` and `setItem()` to properly use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
localStorage.setItem("ClassName", "leftpanel_collapse");
```

```js
$('.left_right_section').addClass(localStorage.getItem("ClassName"));
```

Comment: Now the menu is alwase closed even if it's open before refresh

Comment: that makes sense.  your code is adding a classname to localStorage when you collapse the menu and then always adds that classname back every time the page loads because that value in localStorage persists across page loads.  sounds like you want to [remove the item from localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) when opening the menu.

Comment: i added  ```if (document.querySelector('.leftpanel_collapse') == null) { 

     localStorage.removeItem('ClassName');

    }``` but the menu still closed

Comment: where is that `if` statement running?  does it run whenever the user clicks the menu? 
 normally if you want to react to a user's interaction with the page you would use [event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).  "listen" for the user clicking the menu, and in response, remove the classname from localStorage if the menu is being opened.  add the classname to localStorage if they're closing.

Comment: i'm puting this if statement is a click function but seem not working :  `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').click(function() {
    check = $('.left_right_section').hasClass('.leftpanel_collapse');
    if (check) {
      SetClass();
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      
      console.log('no');
    }
  });
});`